# Get raw code from Comments in ExpressionEngine

Tags: php, jquery, sql, expressionengine

How can I get the raw code of a comment in ExpressionEngine (frontend)?

The thing is this: If a comment contains Code or HTML like [quote]-Tags, the ee-native {comment}-Tag renders this as `<blockquote>Life is like a box of…` … but how can I get the raw code like `[quote]Life is like a box of…`?

I'm currently working on a Quote-Feature (frontend/JavaScript) for native EE comments. Till now I've worked with jQuery.text() or .html() … but both ways you get no tag (.text()) or html-tags (.html()).
Isn't there a way to get the raw comment code (for example into a data-attribute or script-tag) to later use with JavaScript?

**Edit (1):** I've tried SQL — is this the only/best way to do this?

```
<blockquote data-raw="{exp:query sql="SELECT exp_comments.comment AS comment_raw FROM exp_comments WHERE exp_comments.comment_id = {comment_id} "}{comment_raw}{/exp:query}">
  {comment}
</blockquote>
```

**Edit (2):** The SQL works fine, but if there is a `"` inside the raw comment code, the whole thing breaks because the browser thinks this is the closing quote of the «data-raw»-attribute :-/ Is there a Way to 'mask' all characters? (`"` and `'` and `<` and `>` etc.)

**Edit (3):** I now use a `<script>`-Tag to insert the {comment_raw}-code, this way the characters do not disturb.

Answer (score 0):

You'd probably be better off retrieving the raw comment via an ajax call rather than adding a query for every single comment on the page. You'd avoid the performance hit and wouldn't need to worry about storing large strings in data attributes. I'd probably do something like this:

- Create a new 'get_comment' template containing the `{exp:query}` tag with `WHERE comment_id = '{segment_X}'`
- When a user hits the reply/quote button use [jQuery.get()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) to send a request to your get_comment template, passing in the comment_id based on a `data-commentid` attribute on the reply button.
- Update your input's value with the .get() response.